# c# filtering list of list of integers if empty

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of list of integers. How do I filter it of the list of integer inside list is empty.

For example:- `L = [[0,1,2], [], [1], [1,2,3]]`. How do I filter it to get `L = [[0,1,2], [1], [1,2,3]]` using linq?

Here `[0,1,2]` is list of integers.

This is related to my previous question. I have a recursive function which returns a list of list of integers and I need to filter out the empty lists.

```
        int [] num_list = new int[10]{2, 3, 5, 9, 14, 19, 23, 45, 92, 100};

        public List<List<int>> find_solutions(int n, int t, int w)
        {

            if (n == 2)
            {
                List<int> s = new List<int>();
                for (var i=0; i <= t; i++)
                {
                    if (i * num_list[1] + (t - i) * num_list[0] == w)
                    {
                        s.Add(i);
                        s.Add(t - i);
                    }
                }
                return new List<List<int>> { s };
            }

            List<List<int>> f = new List<List<int>>();
            List<List<int>> temp_list = new List<List<int>>();
            for (int i=0; i <= Math.Min(t, w/num_list[n-1]); i++)
            {

                temp_list = find_solutions(n - 1, t - i, w - i * num_list[n - 1]);

                // I strongly believe that i am getting empty list
                // and I should filter out empty list form temp_list
                // and I need to insert 'i' to each list inside list

                foreach(List<int> c in temp_list)
                {
                    c.Insert(0, i);
                }
                f.addRange(temp_list);
            }
            return f;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] allLists = new int[][] { new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }, new int[] { },
    new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } };

int[][] nonEmtpy = allLists.Where(list => list.Any()).ToArray();
```

You can use `Where` and `Any` to filter out any empty entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listOfLists = L; //To use a better name for L
var nonEmptyLists = listOfLists.Where(innerList => innerList.Any());
```

You can iterate over this, and/or call `ToList` or `ToArray` if necessary

Comment: Er... I think you're mixing up your upper and lower case `L`s here.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Thanks for that mate, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in following ways:

```
L.Where(p=>p.Any()).ToList();
L.Where(p=>p.Count > 0).ToList();
```

The Count property is optimized for `ICollection<T>` where T is a type. Any() has to build an enumerator. So the Count property is faster than Any() method

Comment: `Count` is faster, but `Any()` is clearer. I profiled a straightforward check of a list with one item, over 100,000,000 checks `Count` comes out ~30ms `Any()` comes out ~3100. Which means Count runs in ~1% of the time of Any(). However I'd prefer Any(), unless I had a good reason to optimize for Lists (or arrays) and I _knew_ I needed to squeeze every tick out of the processor.

Comment: Clearer to the one that's most important, the person looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using `Where()` and asking for `Count`:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>();
...


list = list.Where(l => l.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
L.Where(i => i.Count() > 0).ToList()
```